# ClassNotFoundException with product flavors and Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a project written mostly in Kotlin, but with some java classes. Project is well advanced now, and I wanted to add the possibility of switching between different environments, for which I used flavors:

```
 productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FABRIC', 'true'
            applicationId = "com.myapp"
        }

        beta {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FABRIC', 'true'
            applicationId = "com.myapp.beta"
        }

        dev {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FABRIC', 'false'
            applicationId = "com.myapp.dev"
        }

    }
```

However when I run in a flavor that isn't production (which does not change applicationId) I get a ClassDefNotFoundException for a java class:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapp.beta.ui.view.ScrollBehavior" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.beta-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.beta-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 33 more
```

I am using Android Studio 3.0 beta 4 with Kotlin plugin version 1.1.3-2.

Build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // Use experimental kapt implementation

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/ttymsd/maven"
    }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"

        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FABRIC', 'true'
            applicationId = "com.myapp"
        }

        beta {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FABRIC', 'true'
            applicationId = "com.myapp.beta"
        }

        dev {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FABRIC', 'false'
            applicationId = "com.myapp.dev"
        }

    }


    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    dependencies {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">


        <activity
            android:name=".ui.dashboard.DashboardListActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Relevant part in the code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_behavior=".ui.view.ScrollBehavior">
```

Comment: Does a full clean & rebuild fix the problem? Does turning instant run off fix it?

Comment: I never have Instant Run on (it sucks). Clean & Rebuild does not fix it sadly

Comment: Please post your manifest package

Comment: @crgarridos just did

Comment: That isnt the manifest, it's a *build.gradle* of your module , look at the file *AndroidManifest.xml*

Comment: geez you are right dunno what i was thinking, its updated now

Comment: provide your full project structure.

Comment: Where do you define or use `"com.myapp.beta.ui.view.ScrollBehavior"`? Might be in a string resource or layout.

Comment: yes! you are right i am referencing it from a layout, but then how can I reference it and still have multiple flavors?

Comment: @tynn just did it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're defining your behavior as

```
app:layout_behavior=".ui.view.ScrollBehavior"
```

which is a relative definition. In this case relative to the app package.

So the name actually used is `context.getPackageName() + name` and thus the application id you defined is used as prefix.

To load the correct behavior you have to define it as a fully qualified name

```
app:layout_behavior="com.myapp.ui.view.ScrollBehavior"
```

Also you could use string resources here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Kotlin issue.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapp.**beta**.ui.view.ScrollBehavior"

From the android [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html)

> Every Android app has a unique application ID that looks like a Java package name, such as com.example.myapp. This ID uniquely identifies your app on the device and in Google Play Store

```
<manifest package="com.myapp" >
```

or sometimes I've even seen *(never use this)*:

```
<manifest package="${applicationId}" >
```

Changing it means that you are changing te reference of your application package. the classes located in `com.myapp` will be searched into `com.myapp.beta`. And then your classes won't be found.

One way to work with, is defining the flavor as *(I put off others values for simplicity)*:

```
prod {
    applicationId = "com.myapp"
}

beta {
    applicationId = "com.myapp.beta"
}

dev {
    applicationId = "com.myapp.dev"
}
```

or just

```
beta {
    applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
}

dev {
    applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
}
```

**Edit after pusblish build.gradle**

Pay attention to add a suffix or a full applicationId :

```
//This will be append to your application id
//applicationIdSuffix = "com.myapp.beta", should be
applicationIdSuffix = ".beta"
```

or

```
//This will replace your application Id
applicationId  "com.myapp.beta"
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when replacing the actual name of my app for a general one so the question was generic. I actually have the values as you specified.

Comment: Application ID does not replace package name. If you place a class in `com.example.foo` package, it will stay there. `R` class will be generated always in the package specified in AndroidManifest.xml. **Don't ever do crazy stuff like this:** `<manifest package="${applicationId}">`